# PHP : HTML formating is not happening while reading the content from XML

Tags: php, xml

I'm reading the contents from an XML file to show the web pages contents, please see the code snippet to read the XML file,

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    $arg = $_GET['content'];
    //echo $arg;
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->load('History.XML');
    $contents = $doc->getElementsByTagName($arg);
    $content1 = $contents->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $content2 = $contents->item(1)->nodeValue;

    ?>

        <p> 
        <?php 
        echo <<<EOM
        $content1 
    EOM;
        ?> 
        </p> 
    </body>
</html>
```

The XML file contents have some HTML formatting tags like `<b>` `<h3>` etc, but reading  and showing those contents from XML , the HTML formatting are not happening. 
Please clarify me if I did any mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nodeValue` in your case is a concatenation of all *text* nodes.
Use [string DOMDocument::saveXML ([ DOMNode $node [, int $options ]] )](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php) instead.

self-contained example:

```
<?php
$arg = 'foo';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadxml('<x>
    <foo><h1>lalala</h1><b>xyz</b></foo>
    <foo>12345</foo>
</x>');
$contents = $doc->getElementsByTagName($arg);
$content1 = $contents->item(0);
$content2 = $contents->item(1);
?>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><?php echo $doc->savexml($content1); ?></p> 
  </body>
</html>
```

prints

```
<html>
  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><foo><h1>lalala</h1><b>xyz</b></foo></p> 
  </body>
</html>
```